# Using counter to create dict of specifc words in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I have a list that looks like :

```
my_list = ['singapore','india','united states','london','paris','india','london','china','singapore','singapore','new york']
```

Now I want a `Counter[dict]` of only specific words in this list

```
Counter(my_list) gives me the following :
Counter({'singapore': 3, 'india': 2, 'london': 2, 'united states': 1, 'paris': 1, 'china': 1, 'new york': 1})
```

But is there a way to create a Counter of only specific words from a list , like for example Counter of words in `['london','india','singapore']`

What would be the fastest way to do this ? My list is very large.

What I tried : `my_list.count('london')` for example. But is there a faster way to achieve this ?

Comment: See if you can find this to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a set to filter the words, for example:

```
from collections import Counter

needles = {'london', 'india', 'singapore'}
haystack = ['singapore', 'india', 'united states', 'london', 'paris', 'india',
            'london', 'china', 'singapore', 'singapore', 'new york']

result = Counter(value for value in haystack if value in needles)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'singapore': 3, 'india': 2, 'london': 2})
```

Comment: I like the analogy, what would be awesome is changing `value` to `needle` lol

Comment: @Daniel thank you , would you know if  this is faster than using count without any benchmarks ?

Comment: @RameshK For only 1 word, count is going to be faster, for multiple words this approach is faster.

Comment: I'm a bit bothered you didn't use `Counter(needle for needle in haystack if needle in needles)`.  It upsets me deeply.